# HLSL: Can't I modify uniform variables inside the vertex program? (arrays)

Tags: arrays, matrix, multiplication, hlsl, uniform

**I'm diving again into learning shaders and trying to get a better understanding about the way they work and I'm having trouble modifying the values of a an uniform array in the vertex program of my shader, and then passing and using those values in the fragment program.**

---

I'm using this shader to do some calculations on "Object A", which holds the shader, based on the local matrix of a bunch of objects "Objects B".

I use those matrices in the vertex program to multiply them with the local position of the vertices of "Object A", which I then want to store those results in an array and pass into the fragment program.

**I can get it working if I put the array I want to modify in a struct** used by the vertex and fragment programs with the **semantic TEXCOORD** but this limits the size of that array to 32, which restricts the functionality even if I used all the TEXCOORD1 <--> to TEXCOORD15.

This also sets more limitations for me since I would like to use multiple arrays to store the maximum items allowed (which I believe is 1024) per array.

---

So I'm having a hard time **understanding why I cannot modify those array values in the vertex program if I use an uniform array**.

My guess is this way of passing data between vertex and fragment programs doesn't work...

---

*Posting basic version of the shader, excluding all the non-relevant code for better readability*

```
CGPROGRAM
            uniform float4x4 _MyMatrixArray [100];
            uniform float4 _WorldPositions [100];

            struct vertexInput{
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct vertexOutput{
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv: TEXCOORD0;
                //float4 _WorldPositions [32] : TEXCOORD1;
            };


            vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    //output._WorldPositions[i] = mul(_MyMatrixArray[i], worldPos);
                    _WorldPositions[i] = mul(_MyMatrixArray[i], worldPos);
                }
            }

            float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    //if (length(input._WorldPositions[i].xyz) > 0.5)
                    if (length(_WorldPositions[i].xyz) > 0.5)
                    {
                        //Do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
ENDCG
```

Using the commented lines works but that greatly limits the functionality of my shader.

**Why can't I modify the values of the array in the vertex program if I declare it outside of a struct? Is there any way to do this?**

**Are there any other approaches that I should be taking when it comes to using large arrays in the way I intend to (chaning and using their values on vertex/fragment programs?**

I'm kinda lost on this one, any info on this is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You declared the array as `uniform` - modifying it would mean it is no longer uniform across the shaders execution

Comment: @UnholySheep I see, so then I could use that uniform array on the vertex/fragment program as long as I don't change the values inside the shader itself? Like I'm doing with the other array "_MyMatrixArray[i]" which has all data predefined in an external C# script?

Comment: Yes, you can read `uniform` variables anywhere inside the shader. Mutable global variables are a bad idea in general, so passing values you need around as parameters is always a better idea

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks a lot! I understand how uniforms are treated now in a shader. I guess I will have to do my matrix multiplications on an external way and then supply them into the uniform shader array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a better approach for this that doesn't involve the need to modify uniform variables inside the shader or to declare them inside a struct.

Providing all the values for the uniform arrays from an external source and then doing distance calculations + doing a pixel discard gives me the results I wanted.